# Калькулятор покупки на Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

Мой пост не совсем по теме, пожалуйста, не ругайте =)

Написал калькулятор JQuery, - просьба взглянуть на JS код и сказать насколько он кривой и что нужно/можно улучшить?

Калькулятор считает почти на лету (после заполнения полей зеленого цвета, он делает подсчет) работает по on('change')

Сам код:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var $price_buy_car = $('#price_buy_car'),
    $price_customs_car = $('#price_customs_car'),
    $engine_capacity = $('#engine_capacity'),

    $our_earnings = $('#our_earnings'),
    $account_use = $('#account_use'),
    $delivery_america = $('#delivery_america'),
    $delivery_container = $('#delivery_container'),
    $delivery_title = $('#delivery_title'),
    $distributions = $('#distributions'),
    $unloading_odessa = $('#unloading_odessa'),
    $certificate = $('#certificate'),
    $assessment = $('#assessment'),
    $broker = $('#broker'),
    $removal_odessa_container = $('#removal_odessa_container'),
    $tow_truck_kharkiv = $('#tow_truck_kharkiv'),
    $forwarding_escort_services = $('#forwarding_escort_services');

  $('input,select ').on('change', function() {

    //Цена авто
    var $price_buy_car_total = parseInt($price_buy_car.val());

    //Расчет Пошлины
    var $duty = parseInt($price_customs_car.val()) * 0.1;
    //Вывод расчета Пошлины
    var $duty_calc = $('#duty').html($duty);

    //Расчет  Акциза
    var $excise_tax = 0.276 * parseInt($engine_capacity.val()) * 1.1;
    //Вывод расчета  Акциза
    var $excise_tax_calc = $('#excise_tax').html($excise_tax);

    //Расчет НДС    
    var $vat = (parseInt($price_customs_car.val()) + $duty + $excise_tax) * 0.2;
    //Вывод расчета НДС    
    var $vat_calc = $('#vat').html($vat);

    // Статические расходы
    var $our_earnings_total = parseInt($our_earnings.val()),
      $account_use_total = parseInt($account_use.val()),
      $delivery_america_total = parseInt($delivery_america.val()),
      $delivery_container_total = parseInt($delivery_container.val()),
      $delivery_title_total = parseInt($delivery_title.val()),
      $distributions_total = parseInt($distributions.val()),
      $unloading_odessa_total = parseInt($unloading_odessa.val()),
      $certificate_total = parseInt($certificate.val()),
      $assessment_total = parseInt($assessment.val()),
      $broker_total = parseInt($broker.val()),
      $removal_odessa_container_total = parseInt($removal_odessa_container.val()),
      $tow_truck_kharkiv_total = parseInt($tow_truck_kharkiv.val()),
      $auction_percent_total = $('#auction_percent option:selected').val(),
      $auction_percent_total_calc = parseInt($auction_percent_total),
      $forwarding_escort_services_total = parseInt($forwarding_escort_services.val());

    var $static_costs_total = $our_earnings_total +
      $account_use_total +
      $delivery_america_total +
      $delivery_container_total +
      $delivery_title_total +
      $distributions_total +
      $unloading_odessa_total +
      $certificate_total +
      $assessment_total +
      $broker_total +
      $removal_odessa_container_total +
      $tow_truck_kharkiv_total +
      $auction_percent_total_calc +
      $forwarding_escort_services_total;

    //Расчет всей стоимости авто    
    var $total = ($duty + $excise_tax + $vat + $static_costs_total) + $price_buy_car_total;
    //Вывод расчета всей стоимости авто
    var $total_calc = $('#Total').html($total);
  });
});
```

```css
.need-data-input {
  background-color: rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.5);
  color: #000;
}

#Total {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Car price calculator</title>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Калькулятор стоимости авто из США</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-126 col-xl-12">

        <form>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price_buy_car">Цена покупки авто</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control need-data-input" id="price_buy_car" placeholder="Цена покупки авто" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price_customs_car">Цена оценки на таможне</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control need-data-input" id="price_customs_car" placeholder="Цена оценки на таможне" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="engine_capacity">Объем двигателя</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control need-data-input" id="engine_capacity" placeholder="Объем двигателя" required>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <br>

          <h2>Статические расходы</h2>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="our_earnings">Наш заработок</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control need-data-input" id="our_earnings" placeholder="Наш заработок" required value="500">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="account_use">Пользование аккаунтом</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="account_use" placeholder="Пользование аккаунтом" required value="150">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="delivery_america">Доставка по Америке</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control need-data-input" id="delivery_america" placeholder="Доставка по Америке" required value="700">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="delivery_container">Доставка контейнера</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="delivery_container" placeholder="Доставка контейнера" required value="750">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="delivery_title">Доставка тайтл</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="delivery_title" placeholder="Доставка тайтл" required value="100">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="distributions">Раздачи</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="distributions" placeholder="Раздачи" required value="400">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="unloading_odessa">Разгрузка Одесса</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unloading_odessa" placeholder="Разгрузка Одесса" required value="120">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="certificate">Cертификат</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="certificate" placeholder="Cертификат" required value="350">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="assessment">Оценка</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="assessment" placeholder="Оценка" required value="150">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="broker">Брокер</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="broker" placeholder="Брокер" required value="150">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="removal_odessa_container">Снятие контейнера Одесса</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="removal_odessa_container" placeholder="Снятие контейнера Одесса" required value="400">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tow_truck_kharkiv">Эвакуатор до Харькова</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tow_truck_kharkiv" placeholder="Эвакуатор до Харькова" required value="250">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleSelect1">% аукциона</label>
                <select class="form-control need-data-input" id="auction_percent">
                <option value="">% аукциона</option>
                <option value="450">от 0 - 3000$ - 450$</option>
                <option value="600">3000$ - 7000$ - 600$</option>
                <option value="750">7000$ - 15000$ - 750$</option>
                <option value="850">15000$ - 25000$ - 850$</option>
                <option value="950">25000$ - 35000$ - 950$</option>
                <option value="2,5">35000$ - выше - 2,5%</option>
              </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="forwarding_escort_services">Услуги экспедирования и сопровождения</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="forwarding_escort_services" placeholder="Услуги экспедирования и сопровождения" required value="500">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <br>
          <h2>Расчет</h2>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <span>НДС - 20%</span>
                <div id="vat">Ожидание входных данных</div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <span>Пошлина - 10%</span>
                <div id="duty">Ожидание входных данных</div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <span>Акциз - 0,276</span>
                <div id="excise_tax">Ожидание входных данных</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <br>
          <h2>Итого:</h2>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              <div id="Total"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1. Ты вешаешь обработчик на все input и select, хотя очевидно — у них есть общий родитель. Используй паттерн делегирования событий.

2. [субъективный комментарий] Код - простыня. При разрастании его не получится поддерживать. Используй концепциюю ООП.

3. [субъективный комментарий] Вроде уже давно перестали пользоваться jQuery для простых задач. Лишнее потребление памяти. Лично мне немного режет глаза, но подчеркну — это субъективно.

Comment: @Влад Волков  - Окей, спасибо за советы, изучу тему. По потреблению памяти тут уже как посмотреть, этот код ее считай не кушает и с теперешним количеством памяти на борту устройств это отчасти нивелируется.  А саму библиотеку jquery как раз и делали для простых задач)

Comment: у Вас 2\3 когда - это объявления переменных, а потом просто простые операции - что тут оценивать? Я бы на Вашем месте запихнул все коэффициенты и правила в опции data для нужных инпутов и написал бы простой цикл, который перебирает все инпуты и совершает какие-то действия в зависимости от data.

Comment: @Peresada я же не просил оценивать) я попросил помочь улучшить код и показать что не верно написано и в какую сторону копнуть что-бы изучить тему и написать его лучше.

Comment: `var time = performance.now(); time = performance.now() - time;` wtf?

Comment: @Peresada а что изменить при использовании data? Получать в data все равно придется через js. По сути выйдет тоже самое что с переменными, или я в этом ошибаюсь?

Comment: @DenisArshavin Вы сделаете код более универсальным, и при добавлении-изменении полей или коэффициентов Вам нужно только править html вывод. Например в data можно хранить json данные которые будут выстраивать логику, типа `data='{"operations" : { "type" : "evyj;bnm", "coef" : "0.8" }}' А в самом JS вы будете только считывать data из инпута, парсить его и в зависимости от построенной логике выполнять действия. Хотя в какой-то степени это может и усложнить, все зависит от того как вы построите структуру `data`

Comment: @Peresada эти вещи я понимаю, я немного о другом) в input будет меняться значение, что бы положить значение из input в data мне нужно будет использовать js а потом снова брать из data и считать.